# Clearcanvas Connection string for ImageServer "EndpointAddress"

Tags: image, dicom, clearcanvas

NOTE:: I have also asked this question on the Clearcanvas forums at:: http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/tabid/69/afv/topic/aff/11/aft/15086/Default.aspx

Hi, i'm making my own ImageViewer in WPF & now need to load DICOM files with the ImageServer. I'm NOT using the Workstation as a starting point, i'm making a viewer from scratch using the (ClearCanvas.Dicom.dll). I have set up the ImageServer on my computer for testing & can connect to it with the workstation app, but not with my app(& that is my problem).

When I try to connect to the ImageServer via the code below the connection times out. I can connect to my ImageServer with the Workstation app. I'm not sure how to configure my connection string I think.

```
{
    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:104/ClearCanvas/ImageViewer/Automation?wsdl");
    StudyRootQueryServiceClient client = new StudyRootQueryServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
    client.Open();    
}
```

Here is the setting I use in the Workstation to connect, so how do I translate this to a connection string??

```
{
    Server Name= ImageServer
    Host= localhost
    AE Title= SERVERAE
    Port= 104
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more details on what's available to you?  Are you building your ImageViewer application using the ClearCanvas workstation as a starting point and do you have all of the services of the workstation available to you?  Are you just using the DICOM library?  Can you edit the question to clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: I have everything available to me yes. Here are the edits I added to my post:: <<--I'm NOT using the Workstation as a starting point, i'm making a viewer from scratch using the (ClearCanvas.Dicom.dll). I have set up the ImageServer on my computer for testing & can connect to it with the workstation app, but not with my app(& that is my problem).-->>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd assume you would want to load the images from the ImageServer via DICOM.  This would require a DICOM C-FIND request against the ImageServer to retrieve the list of studies on the ImageServer.  You would then need to select a specific study and issue a DICOM C-MOVE request to move the study to your application.  Note also that you will need a DICOM Storage SCP application to listen for incoming DICOM associations and your application will have to be configured as a device on the ImageServer.

To issue a C-FIND request using the ClearCanvas DICOM library, the following code could be used:

```
StudyRootFindScu findScu = new StudyRootFindScu();
StudyQueryIod queryMessage = new StudyQueryIod();
queryMessage.QueryRetrieveLevel = QueryRetrieveLevel.Study;
queryMessage.SetCommonTags();

IList results = findScu.Find("LocalAETitle", "SERVERAE", "localhost", 104, queryMessage);

foreach (StudyQueryIod item in results)
{
    string AccessionNumber = item.AccessionNumber;
    string PatientID = item.PatientId;
    string Sex = item.PatientsSex;
    DateTime BirthDate = item.PatientsBirthDate;
    string StudyName = item.StudyDescription;
    string PatientName = item.PatientsName;
    string StudyUID = item.StudyInstanceUid;
    DateTime StudyDate = item.StudyDate.Value;
    string Modality = item.Modality;
    string ReferringPhysiciansName = item.ReferringPhysiciansName;
}
```

Note that if you want to "filter" your query, you could set additional tags to match on in the queryMessage.

Once you've selected a study from the resuts, to Issue a DICOM C-MOVE request, the following code could be used:

```
string studyInstanceUid = "1.1.1."; // Fill in with the real Study Instance UID
ClearCanvas.Dicom.Network.Scu.MoveScuBase moveScu = new ClearCanvas.Dicom.Network.Scu.StudyRootMoveScu("LocalAETitle", "SERVERAE", "localhost", 104, "LocalAETitle");
moveScu.AddStudyInstanceUid(studyInstanceUid);
moveScu.Move();
```

Finally, the ClearCanvas source does have a Storage SCP implementation.  I would suggest looking at the file in Trunk\Dicom\Samples\StorageScp.cs.  This takes a fair amount of extra code to implement.

Comment: Sweet tnx, I am now getting a list of items. I will try & get into the "DICOM Storage SCP" as you mentioned & see how far I can get with that next week. Tnx again for the helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a NOTE / INFO for others::

As "Steve Wranovsky" stated, take a look at StarageScp.cs in the clearcanvas src. In there you will find the StorageScp class that I have successfully used to accomplish retrieving a file from my ImageServer.
First make sure you configure your Device port in your ImageServer under Admin/Configure/Devices to 106 or something.

Then this is how you start the StorageScp class to Listen on your port.

```
StorageScp.StorageLocation = @"C:\Users\USER\Downloads\DICOM\ScpTEST";
StorageScp.StartListening("LocalAETitle", 106);
while(!StorageScp.Started) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
```

Remember to stop Listening when you close your app.

```
StorageScp.StopListening(106);
```

Then you just make your C-Move call to receive your DICOM file while your StorageScp class is listening.

```
MoveScuBase moveScu = new StudyRootMoveScu("LocalAETitle", "SERVERAE", "localhost", 104, "LocalAETitle");
moveScu.AddStudyInstanceUid(StudyUID);
moveScu.Move();
```

Also if you would like to send a file to the ImageServer look at StorageScu.cs & to use the class do something like this...

```
StorageScu scu = new StorageScu();
scu.AddFileToSend(d.FileName);
scu.Send("LocalAETitle", "SERVERAE", "localhost", 104);
```